# C# Load/Unload plugins

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to have ClassLibrary plugins which can be loaded/unloaded. The only way I have found is using an AppDomain but that defeats the purpose as the plugin cannot use the hosts API.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the plugin cannot use the hosts API."?

Comment: If the plugin references the Host then when you load it in another AppDomain I am assuming it loads the Host again in that AppDomain as nothing is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I've done this with 1.1 2.0 and 3.5.  Plus MS now has MEF which is probably what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the plugin cannot use the hosts API," do you mean that you need your plugins to access their host's code?  If so, that sounds like you're wanting a circular dependency, which is not allowed whether your code is dynamically loadable/unloadable or not.  If the plugin needs access to the host's API, you should extract an interface out of that API and place it in a shared library that both plugins and the host app can access:

```
Plugin -> PluginLib <- Host
```

The host can then inject its API object into a property/constructor of the plugin so that the plugin can then invoke the API methods.  Ideally, your plugin libraries should have no dependencies on the host library.  Using an AppDomain for dynamic loading/unloading should be fine once your dependency problems are solved.

Answer (score 1):

The CLR can only unload an entire Appdomain, not an assembly. However there is no problem loading the same assembly in multiple appdomains.

This means that you can inject an instance of a type from assembly A into a new appdomain where it loads Assembly B. B can then use the instance from assembly A to talk to the main appdomain. As long as you dont pass any types from assembly B 'over the border' you'll be able to unload the appdomain and remove assembly B from memory.

Take a look at the [MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) for more info about passing instances over AppDomain borders